I visited Tennesse and Atlanta for 2 weeks as a tourist (B1/B2) visa. Can I get a tax refund on things I purchased?
I visted tennessee and Atlanta in Georgia in the U.S. on a b1/b2 visa for 2 weeks.
Do I qualify for tax refund on goods I purchased, tickets and on my hotel fees?
If so how to file a request?

Generally no jurisdiction whatsoever will refund tax for goods and services that consumed within the jurisdiction, such as tickets, meals, accommodation, and so on.
Many jurisdictions will refund value added tax on goods that are purchased by visitors and exported from the jurisdiction without having been used (in the original packaging, that sort of thing).  As far as I'm aware, no US state does this for its sales tax.

Indeed.  Where it is possible, you normally need to show the goods at the airport and claim the refund there.

My wife just did this in Thailand.  The shop (silk goods) sealed the bag and gave her some forms.  She presented these at a desk in the airport before security.  They glanced at the bag and forms and gave her another form.  She used that form to get the refund after going through security.

Many US states do not charge sales tax if the goods are directly shipped out of the country by the seller. As you said, they do if the goods are delivered (sale is consummated) within their state. Example: California, Texas,

Washington at least allows non-residents to claim sales tax exemption for goods that will be removed from the state. (It might depend on the state of residence, not sure there. I live in Alaska, which at this time does not have a state-level sales tax).

Some places do allow targeted refunds or exemptions for services consumed in order to, for example, encourage international conventions to come. Probably not the US though. Getting a refund even on goods taken out of a US state is not easy, especially for a non-resident, at least from what I've seen with NY.

I confirm @Spehro'speff'Pefhany: hotels and restaurants VAT (on some countries) may be reimbursed, but for such services, there are further requirements: business reasons (and it may be complex, and possibly done by the company). -- Note: and if you ask refund of VAT (exporting goods), usually you should pay VAT on entry of the new country (but for low limits, which may not be an effective use of time for small refunds).
